# Shorthand for generating for loop in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm, you can type `forek` or `fore` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and you'll get

```
foreach (| as $index => $index) {

}
```

and

```
foreach (| as $item) {

}
```

respectively.

In Android Studio (Java), you can type `fori` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and you'll get

```
for (int i = 0; i < |; i++) {

}
```

`|` is where the cursor ends up.

I was wondering if PhpStorm has a similar way of generating `for` structures. I've been trying `fori` but to no avail. Seems rather curious that `forek` and `fore` are included but not the classic `for` with a counter.

Perhaps the shortcut is different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhpStorm only has predefined live templates for `foreach` PHP loops. But you can easily create the corresponding template yourself in **Settings | Editor | Live Templates** (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+(Snippets)+in+PhpStorm), like

```
for($INDEX$ = 0; $INDEX$ < $LIMIT$; $INDEX$++) {
  $END$
}
```

where `expression` for `$INDEX$` is `phpSuggestVariableName()`

[image]